# Multiple ngFor inside tables

Tags: css, angular, html-table

Problem: td with image tag `{{im.url}}` shows images one below the other, but what I need is to show them side by side horizontally, 
 Is it possible to expand/merge that td to a size of first row so that I can put 5 images side by side ?

```
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let row of tasks;  let i = index" colspan="6">
        <td class="text-left" >
          <b>
            <u>{{row.lowtask}}</u>
          </b>
          <tr *ngFor="let t of row.time">
            <td class="text-left">{{t.time1}}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{t.time2}}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{t.time3}}</td>
            <td class="text-right">{{cnvert(t.cur1)}} </td>
            <td class="text-right">{{convert(t.cur2)}} </td>                                       
          </tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let im of row.images">                                         
            <td>
              <img src="{{im.url}}" class="thumb"/>
            </td>                                                                    
          </tr>                                    
        </td>                            
      </tr>                      
     </tbody>
```

Comment: Just move the inner `*ngFor` from the `tr` to the `td` tag

Comment: Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your `ngFor`. Here you go:

```
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let row of tasks;  let i = index" colspan="6">
              <td class="text-left" >
                 <b>
                     <u>{{row.lowtask}}</u>
                 </b>
                  <tr *ngFor="let t of row.time">
                     <td class="text-left">{{t.time1}}</td>
                     <td class="text-center">{{t.time2}}</td>
                     <td class="text-center">{{t.time3}}</td>
                     <td class="text-right">{{cnvert(t.cur1)}} </td>
                     <td class="text-right">{{convert(t.cur2)}} </td>                                       
                   </tr>
                   <tr>                                         
                     <td *ngFor="let im of row.images">
                       <img src="{{im.url}}" class="thumb"/>
                     </td>                                                                    
                   </tr>                                    
              </td>                            
     </tr>                      
 </tbody>
```

Comment: yes but now shows images under every td created above...first image under td {{t.time1}}, second under td {{t.time2}}....etc, but it looks awful because those td's are not the same size so there are different distances between images

Answer (score 0):

wrap your `td` in `<ng-container>`

```
<tbody>
       <tr *ngFor="let row of tasks;  let i = index" colspan="6">
                  <td class="text-left" >
                     <b>
                         <u>{{row.lowtask}}</u>
                     </b>
                      <tr *ngFor="let t of row.time">
                         <td class="text-left">{{t.time1}}</td>
                         <td class="text-center">{{t.time2}}</td>
                         <td class="text-center">{{t.time3}}</td>
                         <td class="text-right">{{cnvert(t.cur1)}} </td>
                         <td class="text-right">{{convert(t.cur2)}} </td>                                       
                       </tr>
                       <tr>  
                        <ng-container  *ngFor="let im of row.images">                                       
                         <td>
                           <img src="{{im.url}}" class="thumb"/>
                         </td>  
                         </ng-container>                                                                  
                       </tr>                                    
                  </td>                            
         </tr>                      
     </tbody>
```

Comment: No need to wrap to `ng-container`

Comment: it's unnecessary. No difference, if `*ngFor` written in `td` element

Comment: I just gave an alternate solution yeah it's same as using `*ngfor` within `td` but Angular doesn't put it in the DOM so it ain't gonna matter.